# Gnuplot: Expression in input data

Tags: gnuplot

Is there a way to specify that input data is an expression that needs to be evaluated?

In my case the data is rational numbers encoded in the format "n/d". Is there a way to tell gnuplot to interpret "n/d" as "n divided by d"?

Example input data:

```
1/9  1 
1/8  2
1/7  3
1/6  4
```

I tried `plot "data" using ($1):2` but this truncates "n/d" to "n".

Update: After some digging in the manual, I found that in this case I can tell gnuplot to interpret "/" as a column separator and then divide the first number by the second as follows: `plot "data" using ($1/$2):3 '%lf/%lf %lf'`

Comment: Nice. Put your update in an answer.

Comment: @maij I was hoping for a way to tell gnuplot to interpret any arithmetic expression but apparently this is not possible.

Comment: @bwcoder yes, it is easily possible with gnuplot _only_, see my answer.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know a gnuplot only answer. But you can use the `system` command to let another program do the work. For example the `bc` program on linux. The following script works for me:

```
result(s) = system(sprintf('echo "%s" | bc -l ~/.bcrc', s)) + 0

set table "data.eval"
plot "data.dat" using 1:(result(strcol(2)))
unset table
```

This is the datafile:

```
1 1/2    
2 1/2.0  
3 4+4    
4 4*5-1  
5 4*(5-1)-(3-7)
6 sin(3.1415)
```

This is the output:

```
# Curve 0 of 1, 6 points
# Curve title: ""data.dat" using 1:(result(strcol(2)))"
# x y type
1  0.5  i
2  0.5  i
3  8    i
4  19   i
5  20   i
6  9.26536e-05  i
```

**Notes:**

- The `set table "data.eval"` prints the values into a file, now it is easier to check the results.
- `strcol(2)` reads the entries of the second column as a string. The expression must not contain white space.
- The function `result` transfers the string to `bc`. The string itself must be quoted, else the shell would complain for example about brackets as in line 5 or 6 of the datafile.
- The option `-l` on bc enables floating point evaluation of expressions like in the first line (1/2 = 0.5 instead of 1/2 = 0), and it defines functions like s(x) for sine and e(x) for exp(x).
- `~/.bcrc` reads some function definitions
- The `system` command returns a string. The string is promoted to a floating point number by adding `0`.

My ~/.bcrc looks like this:

```
pi=4*a(1)
e=e(1)

define ln(x)
{return(l(x))}

define lg(x)
{return(l(x)/l(10))}

define exp(x)
{return(e(x))}

define sin(x)
{return(s(x))}

define fac(x)
{if (x<=1) return(1);
       return(fac(x-1)*x)}

define ncr(n,r)
{return(fac(n)/(fac(r)*fac(n-r)))}
```

Tested with gnuplot 4.6 and bc 1.06.95 on Debian Jessie. On Windows you have the `set` command for integer calculations. It seems that Google knows some other commandline calculators.

Answer (score 0):

It wouldn't be gnuplot if there wasn't a *gnuplot-only* solution.

Simply collect your expressions in a string by "mis"using `stats` and evaluate them via `eval` in a `do for` loop and write the results in a string and convert the values to a number via `real` and plot them.

Check `help stats`, `help do`, `help eval`, `help real` and the example below. Most of the data is taken from @maij's answer. The script works for gnuplot>=5.0 and with some adaptions probably with earlier versions.

**Script:** (works for gnuplot>=5.0, Jan 2015)

```
### evaluate expressions in input data
reset session

$Data <<EOD
 1   1/2        # integer division
 2   1/2.0      # float division
 3   4+4
 4   4*5-1
 5   4*(5-1)-(3-7)
 6   sin(3.1415/2)
 7   2**3
 8   sqrt(9)
EOD

myCol   = 2
myExprs = ''
stats $Data u (myExprs=myExprs.sprintf(' "v=%s"',strcol(myCol))) nooutput

myValues = ''
do for [i=1:words(myExprs)] {
    eval word(myExprs,i)
    myValues = myValues.sprintf(" %g",v) 
}
myValue(n) = real(word(myValues,int(column(n)+1)))
set offsets 0.5,0.5,2,0

plot $Data u 1:(myValue(0)) w lp pt 7 lc "red" ti "Expressions", \
        '' u 1:(myValue(0)):2 w labels offset 0,1 notitle
### end of script
```

**Result:**

[image]